# Difference between Future(Int) and Future{Int} in scala

Tags: scala, future

I am new to Scala and `Future`. In a scenario like following

```
val a = Future(10)
println(a)
val b = Future{20}
println(b)
```

The output is

```
 Future(Success(10))
 Future(<not completed>)
```

I did not understand why using curly braces changes the output. Or What is the basic difference between these two Futures.

Comment: Small hint: if you want to put value that already calculated into Future it is better to use Future.successful(value). This will not schedule extra task in thread pool and Future value will be available instantly.

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case there is no difference. The problem is that you are printing the `Future` immediately after creating it so it is up to the scheduler (and random factors) whether or not the `Future` has completed or not.

I just ran this and got

```
Future(<not completed>)
Future(<not completed>)
```